# Dagger 2: inject beans from two custom independent scopes

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I have two object graphs with custom scopes in Dagger 2. There are 3 components: AppComponent and two subcomponents ComponentA and ComponentB.

When I'm trying to inject objects from both graphs in one place I've got an error:

> Error:(12, 10) error: today.tarasov.daggerindependentscopes.ClassB cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method.
>   today.tarasov.daggerindependentscopes.MainActivity.classB
>   [injected field of type: today.tarasov.daggerindependentscopes.ClassB classB]

Here is my configuration:

**Components**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = AppModule.class)
public interface AppComponent {

    ComponentA plus(ModuleA moduleA);

    ComponentB plus(ModuleB moduleB);

}

@ScopeA
@Subcomponent(modules = ModuleA.class)
public interface ComponentA {

    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);

}

@ScopeB
@Subcomponent(modules = ModuleB.class)
public interface ComponentB {

    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);

}
```

**Scopes**

```
@Scope
public @interface ScopeA {
}
@Scope
public @interface ScopeB {
}
```

**Modules**

```
@Module
public class AppModule {

    private final App app;

    public AppModule(App app) {
        this.app = app;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    App provideApp() {
        return app;
    }
}

@Module
public class ModuleA {
    @ScopeA
    @Provides
    ClassA provideClassA() {
        return new ClassA();
    }
}

@Module
public class ModuleB {
    @ScopeB
    @Provides
    ClassB provideClassB() {
        return new ClassB();
    }
}
```

**Beans**

```
public class ClassA {
}
public class ClassB {
}
```

**Application**

```
public class App extends Application {

    private static App instance;
    private AppComponent appComponent;
    private ComponentA componentA;
    private ComponentB componentB;

    public static App getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        instance = this;
       appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder().appModule(new AppModule(this)).build();
    }

    public AppComponent getAppComponent() {
        return appComponent;
    }

    public ComponentA getComponentA() {
        return componentA;
    }

    public ComponentB getComponentB() {
        return componentB;
    }

    public ComponentA createComponentA() {
        componentA = appComponent.plus(new ModuleA());
        return componentA;
    }

    public ComponentB createComponentB() {
        componentB = appComponent.plus(new ModuleB());
        return componentB;
    }
}
```

And finally trying inject all things in one place

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Inject
    ClassA classA;
    @Inject
    ClassB classB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // injecting classA from ScopeA
        App.getInstance().createComponentA().inject(this);
        // injection classB from ScopeB
        App.getInstance().createComponentB().inject(this);

        if (classA == null || classB == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Injection failed");
        }
   }
}
```

I've also created a [github](https://github.com/d-tarasov/dagger-independentscopes) repo to showcase the problem. My questions is:

- Is it possible to solve this in Dagger 2?
- Whats wrong with my configuration, if possible?
- How to deal in such case, if I'm on a wrong way?

Comment: You cannot use field injection from two different scopes - how is either module supposed to know that it is not meant to provide a given dependency? People typically create scopes for the Activity, like `@ActivityScope @Component(...) public interface MainActivityComponent {...` you can manually resolve the dependencies through the provision methods of the components though.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce could you explain a little bit more what do you mean under 'manually resolve dependencies through the provision methods?

Comment: You would need to add the provided dependency types in your component and then manually get the instance from the component through the provision method. Similarly to how you would use component dependencies (which are functionally the same as subcomponents; but they need provision methods to work)

Comment: Thank you, this way thats works!